# #REF! error in data from Importxml (Google Sheets Xpath/Formula)

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, import, google-sheets-formula

This is my first question here, so please be kind! I'm sure this is quite novice, but here goes:

I am using Importxml to pull some data from a website. Generally everything is fine, but it certain cells the data requires an additional cell and I am presented with a #REF! error reading "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in.." I simply don't understand how to fix it. How do I edit my Importxml formula to remedy this? Or is it the Xpath that needs a fix?

Here is a Sheet I made with the url, xpath, error in question: [REF Error in Importxml](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uNI3O9iPbNm2p4r0XFm9GTfujrafSUb9_wypVpS2q-w/edit?usp=sharing)

I hope everything is pretty clear and explanatory and, most of all, a simple fix. Thanks everyone for humouring this old fool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can wrap it into INDEX an request a specific cell. for example:

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML(B8, C27), 1, 1)
```

in your case it would be:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(B8, C27)), 1, )
```

### update:

see B2 and D2 cells

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(
 {"Artist", "Release", "Format", "Released", "Country", "Style", "Last Sold", "Highest"}, 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("Artist:"&QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(FLATTEN(
 IMPORTXML(B2, "//div[@class='profile']/*|//div[@class='section_content toggle_section_content']/ul/li"))), 
 "(.*:)", "¤$1"),,9^9)," ‎– ", "¤Release:", 1), "*",, 1), "¤")), ":")), 2, 0)))
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p49YCi_nz9ob0Va22ikq7vZ3guVUb9-EbkjYkFQ3Z0E/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to stop import of everything else that I need (Year, country, etc.)

Comment: @DoCu99 try the 2nd formula

Comment: Could you please have another look? This formula seems to work on some entries, but not with others. I should have been more clear, but I was hoping to constrain all entries for "Artist" within one cell, otherwise the columns get disorganized (if that makes sense). I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @DoCu99 answer updated